# Passing new selected value as parameter to 'onchange' method on rich:autocomplete

Tags: richfaces

I want to use `<rich:autocomplete>` to select an item from a list and call an action method when a new value is selected (using this new value in the method).

I have something like this:

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="2"
    autocompleteMethod="#{bean.autocompleteMethod}"
    fetchValue="#{var.name}"
    var="var">
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{var.name}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:autocomplete>
```

The autocomplete method returns a MyObject list:

```
public List<MyObject> autocompleteMethod(String prefix){
    //...
    return results;
}
```

I want to make a method which is called when a new list value is selected but all I have tryed didn't work because I don't know how can I pass the new selected value to the bean.

I have tryed using `onchange="changeMethod('#{var.id}')"` and making a function like:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="changeMethod"
    action="#{bean.changeMethod}">
    <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{bean.idParam}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

It doesn't work with `onselectitem` too, the 'idParam' is always null.

How can I have this new selected value in the method?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler way.

```
<rich:autocomplete autocompleteMethod="#{bean.autocompleteMethod}" value="#{bean.value}">
    <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" />
</rich:autocomplete>
```

The ajax makes sure the value updates when it is selected. If you're working with something else than a String you can use a converter:

```
@FacesConverter("someConverter")
public class SomeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        // find/create object by name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value {          
        return ((MyObject) value).getName();
    }

}
```

Comment: this is a good solution for String lists, but in my case I had a more complex object list and the converter solution doesn't solve the problem...I had to improve a workaround using String list with the name and the id of MyObject like "name(id)" and parsing the chosen value in order to have the correct object. thx anyway!

Comment: The autocomplete works only with strings, if you can identify the object by the value of that string there should be no issue using the converter.

Comment: understood, but in this case is not possible to identify object with name string so i had to make a workaround...thx!